# page looks different on mac Firefox vs pc Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

A  [sign up page on my site](http://frshstudio.com/freedom-sign-up/) is giving me trouble this evening. It shows up fine in all of my macbook pro's browsers(FF, Chrome, Safari), but when I view it in FF on a PC it seems the page somehow breaks- the horizontal layout becomes vertical. Any ideas why this may be?

Viewed in FF on macbook pro-
[image]

Viewed in FF on pc-
[image]

Comment: Which part is supposed to be horizontal I am looking on PC?Input fields and label?

Comment: upload a screen shot. it looks fine to me in except IE 7-8

Comment: @ScottSimpson   How bizarre. This same thing happened a week or so ago with a different site in Safari. Is there anything I can look for that could be causing this? If this is happening on my devices, I have to assume it's happening on some of my reader's devices and that just really isn't acceptable for me.

Comment: @Self_Taught_Programmer the teal/green text and dark text below are supposed to be on the left, and the entire form is supposed to the right. On the pc, however, each unit is displayed in a vertical format instead of left-right.

Comment: @ScottSimpson just added two screenshots to my original question.

Comment: Opened your link and it looks like your Mac screenshot on my PC Firefox (Palemoon, actually, for I can't install anything here) and Chrome (portable). I'm even using a 1024*768 old PC.

Comment: @Passerby thank you for checking. i can't for the life of me figure out what could be causing this, and why it's isolated to one machine! hopefully it's not too widespread..

Comment: Check the Version of FF on PC. It may be older. Of course you still may want to support. You may want to use something like this: http://crossbrowsertesting.com/browsers to test older version of FF. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If this site is online maybe you could post a link to it, also it would be useful if you could post the html and css.
I'd put the left hand content and right hand content in 2 divs with say the left div 40% and the right 50% then float the left div left and the right div right.  Alternately you can absolute position the divs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The link is in the first sentence of my post("sign up page on my site"). The two sides are currently in left and right divs, with fixed widths of 460px. I'll try `position:absolute` when I have access to the pc again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove position:absloute; for left and right div's. it will work. position is not required any way your make float left and right for two div's with proper width so position is not required.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. position:absolute was added only when the person below suggested it might work. In other words, the problem occurred prior to position:absolute  being added.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because of position:absoulte; only the problem occurred. try to remove position.